# How to render 3D animate model using react native (react-native-maps)

Tags: react-native, unity-game-engine

I looking for a way to render an animated character(e.g. obj) on either Google map or Apple map using react-native-maps, at the same time still be able to interact with map, can someone points me to the right direction?

Thanks